# Customzing the Charts using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-charts

I have a sheet with Pivot table and I am creating an Column stacked chart from the table.

I would like to change the colours of Legend entries in chart and would like to have an title for the chart every time I create the chart.

I tried the below code and I'm getting

> Object variable or with block variable not set

I get the error in the line

```
cht.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(155, 213, 91)
```

Could anyone, tell me how I could create chart for my requirements. I have added an image of my current chart and required chart.

```
Sub chart11()
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim cht As Chart

    If ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Set ptable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
    Set ptr = ptable.TableRange1
    Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
    sh.Select

    With ActiveChart
        .SetSourceData ptr
        .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    End With

    cht.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(155, 213, 91)
    cht.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 5
    cht.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 40
    cht.HasTitle = True    
    cht.ChartTitle.Text = "Default Chart"
End Sub
```

This is the chart generated by my code now, if I comment the error line:

[image: This is the chart generated by my code now, if I comment the error line.]

I would like to have a chart of this type with change in colour legends and chart title:

[image: I would like to have a chart of this type with change in colour legends and chart title]

Comment: You never assign `cht` to anything?!

Comment: @FunThomas means ?

Comment: means something like `Set cht = ActiveChart` is missing. You only declared `cht` as a chart but the variable is empty if you don't set it to some existing or new chart.

Comment: @Peh I will try this

Comment: @Peh after doing so, I get an error automation or unspecified error

Comment: You never defined ptabel or ptr. Make sure you always put Option Explicit on the top of your programs to prevent these errors in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use cht.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 5 and MaximumScale.
Because Pivot chart do not assist Scatterchart.
Only in scatter chart, you can set xlCategory Scale.

```
Sub chart11()
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim cht As Chart

    If ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Set ptable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
    Set ptr = ptable.TableRange1
    Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
    sh.Select
    Set cht = ActiveChart
    With cht
        .SetSourceData ptr
        .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    End With

    cht.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) '<~~ Red
    cht.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0) '<~~ green
    'cht.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 5
    'cht.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 40
    cht.HasTitle = True
    cht.ChartTitle.Text = "Default Chart"
End Sub
```

Comment: could you please provide me the colour code for the above graph , I have showed for green and Red

Comment: @Jenny:  I modified my answer.

Comment: RGB is Red,Green,Blue  of Light.